# Java XML resource bundle and HTML content

Tags: java, xml, resourcebundle

Need to store HTML content as a value in the resource bundle (XML format). The HTML tags are conflicting with the XML tags. How can I store the HTML string without using character entity references `(&lt; and &gt;)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it between [`<![CDATA[` and `]]>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using "CDATA ". CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.

see example here.
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp